# Why is WooCommerce function not overriding the default function in child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a child theme that I am trying to override a WooCommerce function.

WooCommerce file in plugin location: `woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php`. I created a new file in the same hierarchy in my child theme and it's located here: `my-child-theme/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php`

My edited section is I commented out the product title in child theme:

```
/**
 * Product Summary Box.
 *
 * @see woocommerce_template_single_title()
 * @see woocommerce_template_single_rating()
 * @see woocommerce_template_single_price()
 * @see woocommerce_template_single_excerpt()
 * @see woocommerce_template_single_meta()
 * @see woocommerce_template_single_sharing()
 */
//add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 ); //commented
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_sharing', 50 );
```

However, when I goto my product page, I still see the title.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php` is correct? If so then that's your problem, as you can only override the files in woocommerce's `templates` directory.

Comment: Thanks, but how come we can't edit `includes` directory? but regardless I updated the `title.php` in `template/single-product/` directory but i don't see the changes either.

Comment: What's your directory structure? The `template` directories need to exactly match inside a `woocommerce` directory in your theme: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: WooCommerce Plugin: `woocommerce/templates/single-product/title.php`

My custom file: `Mint Child: title.php (woocommerce/templates/single-product/title.php)`

Comment: You don't need `templates` in your child theme. The path should be `yourtheme\woocommerce\single-product\title.php`.

Comment: Thanks... so the only thing I can change are inside the `template` folder?

Comment: Btw that worked! I am just starting out modifying the plugin so thanks for the guidance

Comment: Yes you can only override the `templates` directory. But you can also change things via hooks if needed. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove action `woocommerce_single_product_summary` to this work properly.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'remove_woocommerce_single_product_summary', 10 );
function remove_woocommerce_single_product_summary() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
}
```

Just add this to your `functions.php` and will do the magic.

You also can try to add `remove_action()` out of the `add_action()`. Just like this...

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 15 );
```

...directly to `functions.php`

Play with it.

---

**TIPS & TRICKS**

If you want to change your HTML in the title or do anything you want, here is example:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'remove_woocommerce_single_product_summary', 10 );
function remove_woocommerce_single_product_summary() {

    // First, we remove it
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
    
    // Second, we add new title
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_my_new_title', 1 );
    
}
function woocommerce_my_new_title(){
    echo '<h1 class="some-my-custom-classes">' . the_title() . '</h1>';
}
```

> If your active theme does not support Woocommerce and you want to add
> a Woocommerce template to your active theme, you must register
> WooCommerce, or give Woocommerce features.
>
> Check out these links for more details:
>
> https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Declaring-WooCommerce-support-in-themes
>
> https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

**One important thing:**

If you change the template folder within the Woocommerce plugin, there is a good chance that you will lose your settings after the plugin update. That is why it is better to work in an active theme.

Comment: Thanks @Ivijan! So although I was told I cant override anything other than the `template` folder, I can still use `add_action()` to override, even function from the `include` folder within my `functions.php` file right?

Comment: If you need to change only `woocommerce_template_single_title`, you don't need to include Woocommerce template into your theme. Just need to add hooks into `functions.php` . But if your theme not support Woocommerce and you want to add Woocommerce template to your child theme, you need to register Woocommerce to your active theme. Check this link for that: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Declaring-WooCommerce-support-in-themes

Answer (score -1):

```
function my_custom_action() { 
    echo '<p>Hello here</p>';
};     
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_custom_action', 15 );
```

Comment: this will add additional title to his title

Comment: Also, it's recommended to explain how your code addresses/solves the OP's question. Code only answers are frowned upon. Adding info allows visitors to quickly zoom in on the important bits, is quicker to cognitively digest, and helps fire visitors learn, and apply knowledge to their own code. This then favors Q &A for knowledge, over "give me the code" as a service Q and A. It also keeps quality high for SO as a platform.